# How to bind pdo values in foreach loop

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I have this code written for PHP (PDO) -> SQL server. It throws no error, but won't return anything from the DB. I have tried running the SQL it outputs in SQL server management studio and it works perfect. Also, I am outputting the parameters to bind together to make sure it all looks good and it does. For some reason on execution the binds are preventing the SQL running properly. Is there something wrong with this method? Is it even possible to bind in array loops like i am trying here? Code is below, thanks in advance.

```
public function insertStaff( $table, $param )
{
    $qStr = '';
    foreach( $_POST as $k => $v )
    {
        if( $k == 'dummy' || $v == '' )
        {
            $qStr .= '';
        }
        else
        {
            $qStr .= '?,';
        }
    }
    $qStr = rtrim( $qStr, ',' );
    $sql = "INSERT INTO ? ($qStr) VALUES ($qStr)";
    $stmt = $this->c->prepare( $sql );
    //bind table
    $stmt->bindValue( 1, $table, PDO::PARAM_STR );
                        $output = '';
    $x = 2;
    foreach( $_POST as $k => $v )
    {
        if( $k !== 'dummy' && $v !== '' )
        {
            $stmt->bindValue( $x, $k, PDO::PARAM_STR );
            $output .= '<hr>'.$x.' => '.$k;
            $x++;
        }
    }
    foreach( $_POST as $k => $v )
    {
        if( $k !== 'dummy' && $v !== '' )
        {
            $stmt->bindValue( $x, $v, PDO::PARAM_STR );
            $output .= '<hr>'.$x.' => '.$v;
            $x++;
        }
    }
    //return $output;
    if( $stmt->execute() )
    {
        return 'success';
    }
    else
    {
        return 'fail';
    }
}
```

Comment: `INSERT INTO ? ($qStr)` isn't going to work. You cannot use placeholders to specify identifiers (database/table/column names, functions, etc etc), and nor should you. You can only use them to specify values.

Comment: Oh that's such a bummer, I wanted to make one function to handle inserting data into any of my tables. Is there another way to do that?

Comment: There are horrible, nasty ways to do it. But don't. You don't *want* a single function to do this. Your code should be explicit about which entities in the database it is dealing with. The above approach, if it worked, would be wide open to people doing things like inserting users into the grant tables and all manner of horrifying security holes.

Comment: Wow. It looks like a Week of PDO Insert Functions on Stack Oveflow.

Comment: Fair enough, it's for a password protected admin page so I figured that would pretty much handle the security. Guess I'll just have to write a load of code instead..

Comment: No need for loads of code. Try this one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17695188/285587 More examples in [PDO tag Wiki (at the bottom)](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info)

Comment: Beware generalized DB wrapper methods, as @DaveRandom said, your database interactions should be tied to specific actions. If you are simply trying to create a DB wrapper class to loosely couple your specific DB from your system, then consider a simpler approach. Just use PDO->query(SQL,Array of Values)